# How To Choose Which IoC Container WPF Prism Application Use?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I Am Developing Application With Prism 7 and .Net 6 and MediatR , My app.xaml is

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        var bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
        bootstrapper.Run();
    }
}

class Bootstrapper : PrismBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        //I Want To Use Unity Here
    }
}
```

the problem is i want to use extension method that is designed for IUnityContainer
but i cant as i have IContainerRegistry  not IUnityContainer in RegisterTypes method in my
Bootstrapper

```
  public static IUnityContainer RegisterMediator(this IUnityContainer container, ITypeLifetimeManager lifetimeManager)
    {
        return container.RegisterType<IMediator, Mediator>(lifetimeManager)
            .RegisterInstance<ServiceFactory>(type =>
            {
                var enumerableType = type
                    .GetInterfaces()
                    .Concat(new[] { type })
                    .FirstOrDefault(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>));

                return enumerableType != null
                    ? container.ResolveAll(enumerableType.GetGenericArguments()[0])
                    : container.IsRegistered(type)
                        ? container.Resolve(type)
                        : null;
            });
    }
```

prism support several IoC Container , DryIoc , shiny , but there is really no documentation how to change default IoC Container ,How To Choose Which IoC Container WPF Prism Application Use ? in this case i want to choose Unity so i can use my mediatR Extension ,I have search the whole website but with no success.
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Prism.Unity` namespace, there is an extension method for `IContainerProvider`.

```cs
public static IUnityContainer GetContainer(this IContainerProvider containerProvider)
```

You can use this inside your `PrismBootstrapper`.

```cs
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    IUnityContainer container = Container.GetContainer();
}
```

Comment: I Don't Know How To Say Thank You . You Saved Me From getting Crazy . :-) Thank You .